# How to get table usage stats?

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

Is there a way to get table usage stats like number of select, insert, update, delete on a specific table without using auditing?

version: ASE-16 EBF 27304

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [monOpenObjectActivity](https://help.sap.com/viewer/ad4a1ddf1bf34768841bd09d1eddf434/16.0.4.0/en-US/aba20430bc2b1014a568a4cb74ec9ef2.html) may be of use; the columns `Updates`, `Inserts` and `Deletes` are described as `'number of <operation>s performed on this object'` which I'm assuming are **not** duplicates of the sibling columns named `RowsUpdated`, `RowsInserted` and `RowsDeleted` which represent a running count of total rows affected by said <operation>; as for the number of `Select`s ...

Comment: ... perhaps the `Scan` column will be of use but I'm guessing that will also count times a table was referenced/joined in a `update/insert/delete` but not actually `updated/inserted/deleted`; also not sure how any of these counts are affected by trigger firings (ie, are SQL statements fired in a trigger counted as part of the parent txn's operation or do the trigger queries count as a separate operation?)

Comment: @markp-fuso Thank you so much for your help.  Being away from Sybase for so long and I totally forgot about the mon tables.